# Erro ao executar o admin do PostgreSQL:

Tags: postgresql

Eu baixei o Postgre 9.6 e instalei tudo "default". Só que na hora de executar a interface gráfica do Postgre,  o "pgadmin4" dá o seguinte erro: "The application server could not be contacted".

Comment: Tenta acessar o postgres via psql pra ver se o server está executando.

Comment: Guiliana, não sei ao certo como fazer isso. Ao executar o psql aparece uma linha escrito:   Server [localhost]:      O que eu faço?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido: bastou clicar no Pgadmin4 pra executá-lo de novo que funcionou. As vezes só conecta na terceira tentativa.